FInding deflection on a uniform beam with supports ~ Incorrect answer
Hello I am asked to find deflection of beam in millimetres at different points.
The uniform beam is 3.55 meters long with a flexural rigidity of 32269Nm^2
It is under a uniform load of 92N/m and is supported with a fixed support on the left and a simple support on the right.
These are the x coordinates I had to evaluate and the answer I got for each:
(my answer is the y(x) value in millimeters)
x=0.36, y(x) = −0.163851
x=0.96, y(x) = −0.006993
x=1.56, y(x) = −0.010678
x=2.84, y(x) = −0.289602
x=3.16, y(x) = −0.477706
I will briefly explain my working out, answers can be found at the end of it.
Firstly I used the Euler Bernoulli beam theory formula for deflection:

w = uniform load (N/m)
x = position along the beam (m)
E = modulus of elasticity (N/m²)
I = moment of inertia (m^4)
L = length of the beam (m)
I then computed each deflection value using this formula:

However my answers gotten from this werent even close.
Am I using the wrong method? Or using incorrect values?
the answers were:
x=0.36, y(x) = 0.243841
x=0.96, y(x) = 1.237706
x=1.56, y(x) = 2.165999
x=2.84, y(x) = 1.690490
x=3.16, y(x) = 1.001585
Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated thank you guys !

Check your use of theory with: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/beam-stress-deflection-d_1312.html
